# compare meta_query in get_posts arguments

Tags: wp-query, custom-field, meta-query

I like to exclude certain posts with a custom field. So if `my_custom_field_ignore` isset AND `1` ignore this post. If it's not set include it.

This is what I have

```
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => $post_type,
        'offset' => $offset,
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'my_custom_field_ignore',
                'value' => '1',
                'compare' => '!=',
            )
        )
    );
```

This works only for posts where the `my_custom_field_ignore` is set to something else than `1`

How can I include all posts (of course not the ones with `my_custom_field_ignore = 1`)?

**Edit:**

This is how it work on WP 3.5+

```
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'my_custom_field_ignore',
            'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
        )
    )
```

This simple search for the appearance of `my_custom_field_ignore` so the value will be ignored. While this could work in the first place users may get confused when they changed `1` to `0` and expect to be included.

Seems 3.3 and 3.4 needs some conditional check though.

**Edit 2**

Seems the checked answered does the trick (at least for 3.5+). For some odd reason it ignores the very first post "Hello World". After adding `my_custom_field_ignore` and removing it afterwards it's working

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If we define the conditions:

```
A: my_custom_field_ignore EXISTS
B: my_custom_field_ignore = 1
```

then `NOT ( A && B )` is equivalent to:

```
NOT ( A ) || NOT ( B )
```

meaning in our case:

```
( my_custom_field_ignore NOT EXISTS ) ||  ( my_custom_field_ignore != 1 )
```

We could therefore try the following for WP 3.5+ (untested):

```
 $args = array(
    'post_type'  => $post_type,
    'offset'     => $offset,
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key'     => 'my_custom_field_ignore',
            'value'   => '1',
            'compare' => '!=',
        ),
        array(
            'key'     => 'my_custom_field_ignore',
            'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
            'value'   => '1',     #<-- just some value as a pre 3.9 bugfix (Codex)
        ),
    )
);
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll check but should work with 3.3+

Comment: I updated the answer, the `NOT EXISTS` is only supported for WP 3.5+ according to the Codex.

Comment: sorry this doesn't work from 3.3 up to 4.0

Comment: I just tested this on a vanilla WP 4.0 install, where it works as expected. What is your output? What does the SQL query look like in your case?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/bLSHErMH what's yours? (I've 'numberposts => 1' as well but I guess this doesn't matter)

Comment: yes I got the same SQL query, apart from the limit. Do you have any extra spaces in your meta values? Do you get no result at all? Is your post type correct? Are you testing this in WP 4.0?

Comment: no, I pass the args to the `get_posts` function. I'll do some test an keep you updated. Thanks you meanwhile!

Comment: I've updated my questions with a possible solution but has some counterparts

Comment: Strange, I'm not sure why it isn't working for you. Make sure your saved meta values are without any extra spaces. On my vanilla WP 4.0 install I created `10` posts. I then updated `3` of them with the custom field `my_custom_field_ignore`, two of them with the value of `1` and a single one with the value of `0`. Then I ran the above query with `posts_per_page=10` and I got 8 posts returned from that query. The posts with the custom field values equal to `1` were excluded as expected.

Comment: ok, I'll double check this - maybe

Comment: The post which was not displayed was the "Hello World" post. Everything works fine if I add the `my_custom_field_ignore` to this post and remove it afterwards. Strange thing though.

Comment: that's strange but glad to hear you got it working ;-)

Answer (score 1):

you have to use the serialize function in case you are using integers:

```
$args = array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'my_meta_key',
            'value' => serialize(strval($my_vale)),
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )
    )
);
$posts = get_posts( $args );
```

and you are ready,

```
print_r($posts);
```

and see the results